# How do I keep str(numpy.array) from automatically inserting a newline

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a 100x6 numpy array to a data file using

```
# print  array to file
data = open("store.dat", "w")
for j in xrange(len(array)):
    data.write(str(array[i]) + "\n")
```

but when the file writes, it automatically splits the line after 68 characters i.e. 5 columns of a 6 column array. For example, I want to see

```
[ 35.47842918  21.82382715   3.18277209   0.38992263   1.17862342   0.46170848]
```

as one of the lines, but am getting

```
[ 35.47842918  21.82382715   3.18277209   0.38992263   1.17862342
0.46170848]
```

I've narrowed it down to a problem with `str(array[i])` and it deciding to make itself a new line.

Secondly, is there a better way to be going about this? I'm very new to python and know little about properly coding in it. Ultimately, I'm writing out a simulation of stars to later be read by a module that will render the coordinates in VPython. I thought, to avoid the problems of real-time rendering I could just pass a file once the simulation is complete. Is this inefficient? Should I be passing an object instead?

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to save the data persistently on disc or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps it would be more convenient to write it using [`numpy.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) instead?

Alternatively, you can also use:

```
numpy.array_str(array[i], max_line_width=1000000)
```